# MySQL query WHERE condition

Tags: mysql

I have the table **`doTable`** in MySQL database.
In **`doTable`** I have three fields:

```
IdCode  int 11
State   char 2
id      int 11
```

The values of field **`State`** for single **`IdCode`** could be: A, B, C, D or TC.

```
+---------+-------+----+
| IdCode  | State | id |
+---------+-------+----+
| 6027713 | TC    |  1 |
| 7057816 | B     |  2 |
| 7047412 | TC    |  3 |
| 7047412 | A     |  4 |
| 6027713 | B     |  5 |
| 6027713 | B     |  6 |
| 6027713 | C     |  7 |
| 6040309 | TC    |  8 |
| 6040309 | A     |  9 |
| 6040309 | TC    | 10 |
| 6040309 | A     | 11 |
| 4041208 | TC    | 12 |
| 7060912 | TC    | 13 |
| 7060912 | D     | 14 |
+---------+-------+----+
```

I need extract all rows of **`doTable`** where the **`State`** value are TC only when the same **`IdCode`** contains A, B, C or D.

I need this output:

```
+---------+-------+----+
| IdCode  | State | id |
+---------+-------+----+
| 6027713 | TC    |  1 |
| 7057816 | B     |  2 |
| 7047412 | TC    |  3 |
| 7047412 | A     |  4 |
| 6027713 | B     |  5 |
| 6027713 | B     |  6 |
| 6027713 | C     |  7 |
| 6040309 | TC    |  8 |
| 6040309 | A     |  9 |
| 6040309 | TC    | 10 |
| 6040309 | A     | 11 |
| 7060912 | TC    | 13 |
| 7060912 | D     | 14 |
+---------+-------+----+
```

And exclude in the output the row with ID number 12 because I don't have values A, B, C or D for the same `IdCode`

```
+---------+-------+----+
| IdCode  | State | id |
+---------+-------+----+
| 4041208 | TC    | 12 |
+---------+-------+----+
```

I have tried this query but Empty set.

```
mysql> SELECT
    *
FROM
    `dotable`
WHERE
    (
        State = 'A'
        OR State = 'B'
        OR State = 'C'
        OR State = 'D'
    )
AND State = 'TC';
Empty set

mysql>
```

Can you help me?

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `dotable`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dotable`;
CREATE TABLE `dotable` (
  `IdCode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `State` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of dotable
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('6027713', 'TC', '1');
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('7057816', 'B', '2');
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('7047412', 'TC', '3');
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('7047412', 'A', '4');
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('6027713', 'B', '5');
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('6027713', 'B', '6');
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('6027713', 'C', '7');
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('6040309', 'TC', '8');
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('6040309', 'A', '9');
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('6040309', 'TC', '10');
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('6040309', 'A', '11');
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('4041208', 'TC', '12');
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('7060912', 'TC', '13');
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES ('7060912', 'D', '14');
```

Comment: What you mean by `AND State='TC'` in the where clause?

Comment: I mean that if you don't include this condition does not extract `State = 'TC'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `dotable`
WHERE IdCode IN 
    (SELECT IdCode 
     FROM `dotable`
     WHERE State IN ('A','B','C','D'))
```

**Explanation:**

Inner query selects the IdCodes which as atleast one state from the values A,B,C and D. Outer query selects all records which has IdCodes from the result of inner query.

**Result:**

```
IDCODE  STATE   ID
6027713 TC      1
7057816 B       2
7047412 TC      3
7047412 A       4
6027713 B       5
6027713 B       6
6027713 C       7
6040309 TC      8
6040309 A       9
6040309 TC      10
6040309 A       11
7060912 TC      13
7060912 D       14
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac9db/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select f.*
from dotable f
join (select distinct idcode
      from dotable 
      where state in ('A','B','C','D') ) x
on x.idcode = f.idcode
```

[SQLFiddle Here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40427c/1)

Answer (score 0):

The code below fill you´r needs

```
mysql> SELECT
    *
FROM
    `dotable`
WHERE
    (
        State = 'A'
        OR State = 'B'
        OR State = 'C'
        OR State = 'D'
        AND IdCode = (SELECT IdCode WHERE State = 'TC')
    )
;
```